# How to get access token secret for StockTwit API?

Tags: python, api, authentication, oauth, stocktwits

I've already got the consumer key, consumer secret, and access token, but I don't know how to get the access token secret. This code works but I just need the access token secret. Thanks in Advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access stocktwits API
consumer_key = "something"
consumer_secret = "something"
access_token = "something"
#access_token_secret = ""

#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords
    stream.filter(track=['Hillary Clinton', '#Hillary', 'Donald Trump', '#Trump'])
```

Answer (score 0):

StockTwits does not provide an `access_token_secret`. Once you have an `access token`, that token can be used on all requests to the API. You'll want to see of your OAuthHandler class allows only setting an `access_token`. It should.